# How can i implement web API in Orchard custom module

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.8, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

I have one web API URL and it's returns some XML values, how can I retrieve that XML values into my custom module.

API URL like: www.website.com/api/GetValue?value1=23&value2=newvalue&searchItem=products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, here theres a post from a while[webapi route](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/building-a-webapi-route-in-orchard)

Orchard uses MVC 5.2.3 in its latest version. so anything you can do with that, you can do with Orchard.

Check some other posts or even check someone questions in SO, like:[WebApi Route returns Not Found in Orchard Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318514/webapi-route-returns-not-found-in-orchard-module)

That should get you coding again